# Cassandra vs Mongodb running costs?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, hosting

We are planning to create a public website, and we're in the process of choosing suitable Database for it. After discussions it was suggested to go with NOSQL databases as it would be easier for scaling in future. 
In our website we expect regular writes and lot of reads, and it seems either Cassandra or MongoDB would best suit for it.

Kindly suggest between Cassandra and MongoDb which database would be easier on hosting and maintenance and cheaper on hosting charges.

Also please suggest some providers for better and low cost hosting for both cassandra and MongoDb.

Comment: I use compose.io for mongo hosting and it is $18/month for each GB of storage. There is a 30 day trial, but it does not support Cassandra.

Comment: http://www.instaclustr.com is probably an analog to compose.io for managed hosting for cassandra.